# Fastest method of splitting string into an array in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have a PHP script which splits strings into arrays using prey_split.
The preg_split code is:

```
preg_split("~(?<!\*):~", $val);
```

Which essentially splits the string where there is a colon, without a preceding asterisk.
For example: `"h*:el:lo"` turns into `array("h*:el", "lo")`

This process is quite resource intensive and slow when splitting large amounts of strings.
Is there a faster method to achieve this?

Comment: You can use explode function to split string into array

Comment: Im afraid there won't be a faster alternate to using a regular expression, because of that condition that before colon there should not be an `*`. Otherwise you could try `explode` and compare the results

Comment: only other way I can think of is to loop over the string yourself and manually build the array, but it's probably slower than using preg.

Comment: @bhumi: in general, yes, but explode doesn't support regexes, and does a blind split. OP wants `*:` excluded from split points.

Comment: @MarcB - I can confirm than string looping is like 10 times slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you required to use `preg_split()`? Because it's easier to use `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^|:)([^*:]+(?:\*.[^*:]+)*)/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$string = "h*:el:lo";
$string = str_replace("*:", "#", $string);
$array = explode(":", $string);
```

I'm not sure of what the speed will be like., but once you remove the *: bits form the string, its simple to explode. Perhaps you can put the *: back in after the operation if you need it.

Comment: I haven't tested thoroughly but getting the `*:` back seems to be very slow, even with `array_map()`.

Comment: Perhaps its not needed, unless its for display purposes. I have had an idea, watch the edit on my post shortly.

Comment: Now theres no need to put the *: back in. We leave them in place prior to the split.

Comment: Now your code is faster because it no longer follows the spec.

Comment: How are you testing the timing of the script?

Comment: 25,000 iterations of a 1,600 char string and `microtime(true)`. Please note that your first answer was correct but you edit isn't: you no longer consider `*:` separately.

Comment: I noticed, Im trying to roll it back, but looks like I will have to manually do it